# Why is Hibernate throwing an invalid column exception? My query runs well in Oracle, but throws an exception in Java code

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Constants .java

```
 public static  final String A=" SELECT  name as teamName,location as bookingLoc FROM table where emp_ps_id = :empPSID and rownum<2" ;

 public static  final String A=" SELECT  name as team,location as booking FROM table where emp_ps_id = :empPSID and rownum<2" ;
```

If I use these queries with Hibernate, first one throws an `invalid column name exception` and the second one produces correct result.

```
 public Details getDetails(final String psid) {
        final String finalQuery = Constants.A;
        return (Details) entityManager.createNativeQuery(finalQuery, Details.class)
                .setParameter("empPSID", psid)
                .getSingleResult();
    }
```

Comment: How can this be possible , in the first query there is camelCasing and not producing correct results . But the second one , with no camel casing produces the correct result .Please help .

Comment: See and compare the `Details` entity and the corresponding table. Also, it would've been great if you'd provide more log of what *exactly* it says is an invalid column.

Comment: Hibernate tries to retrieve from the JDBC `ResultSet` every field on the result class, i.e. `Details`. In the error case it does not find the field `team` as there is no such a field in the `ResultSet`.

Comment: @sj123: any feedback on given comments / answers?

Answer (score 0):

As no [explicit](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-sql-resultset-mapping) query mapping is given, the [implicit](https://dzone.com/articles/hibernate-tips-how-to-map-native-query-results-to-1) mapping is taking place and thus the aliased names and types in the query (those after `as` such as `teamName`) needs to correspond to fields on the result class `Details`.

Synchronizing the aliased names and types between the query and result class will fix the problem. Note that every fields on the result class needs to be delivered by the query.